# ¿Cómo detectar cambios en un campo dentro de un objeto en una colección de MongoDB usando Spring Boot?

Tags: java, base-de-datos, mongodb, spring-boot

Tengo una colección en MongoDB que tiene un campo llamado "attributes" que es un objeto que contiene varios campos dentro. Estoy tratando de detectar cuando hay un cambio en el campo "ESTADO_ENVIO" dentro de este objeto utilizando Spring Boot y el driver de MongoDB. He intentado agregar un filtro para detectar estos cambios en mi pipeline, pero no parece estar funcionando correctamente.

He utilizado el método "exists" en mi filtro para detectar si el campo "userAct" en la colección ha sido actualizado, y esto ha funcionado correctamente. Sin embargo, cuando intento detectar un cambio en el campo "ESTADO_ENVIO" dentro del objeto "attributes", no funciona.

Aquí está el pipeline que he utilizado para intentar detectar estos cambios:

```
ChangeStreamIterable<Document> changeStreamIterable = mongoTemplate.getMongoDatabaseFactory()
    .getMongoDatabase()
    .watch(pipeline());

public List<Bson> pipeline() {
    List<Bson> pipeline = Arrays.asList(
        Aggregates.match(Filters.and(
            eq("operationType", "update"),
            eq("ns.coll", COLL_KEY)
            //Filters.exists("updateDescription.updatedFields.userAct"), // esto funciona
            //Filters.exists("updateDescription.updatedFields.attributes.ESTADO_ENVIO") // esto no funciona
        ))
    );
    return pipeline;
}
```

¿Alguien más ha tenido problemas similares al intentar detectar cambios en campos dentro de objetos en MongoDB utilizando Spring Boot y el driver de MongoDB? ¿Hay alguna solución conocida para este problema?

Está es la colección:

```
{
  "_id": "111111",
  "userAct": "user",
  "attributes": {
    "ESTADO_ENVIO": "X"
  }
}
```

Intenté este pipeline para que detectará cambios en el campo ESTADO_ENVIO y no lo detectaba, sin embargo con el Filters.exists comentado si funciona.

```
public List<Bson> pipeline() {
    List<Bson> pipeline = Arrays.asList(
        Aggregates.match(Filters.and(
            eq("operationType", "update"),
            eq("ns.coll", COLL_KEY)
            //Filters.exists("updateDescription.updatedFields.userAct"), // esto funciona
            Filters.exists("updateDescription.updatedFields.attributes.ESTADO_ENVIO") // esto no funciona
        ))
    );
    return pipeline;
}
```

Comment: ¿Tu deseas detectar cuando hay cambios en tu colección?

Answer (score 0):

Para detectar cambios en el valor del campo `ESTADO_ENVIO` dentro del objeto `attributes`, debes utilizar el operador `$set` en tu pipeline. Aquí te muestro cómo sería el pipeline actualizado:

```
public List<Bson> pipeline() {
    List<Bson> pipeline = Arrays.asList(
        Aggregates.match(Filters.and(
            eq("operationType", "update"),
            eq("ns.coll", COLL_KEY),
            Filters.exists("updateDescription.updatedFields.attributes.ESTADO_ENVIO")
        )),
        Aggregates.project(Projections.fields(
            Projections.include("attributes.ESTADO_ENVIO"),
            Projections.excludeId()
        )),
        Aggregates.addFields(new Field<>("old_ESTADO_ENVIO",
            new Document("$ifNull", Arrays.asList("$attributes.ESTADO_ENVIO", null))
        )),
        Aggregates.match(Filters.expr(
            new Document("$ne", Arrays.asList(
                "$attributes.ESTADO_ENVIO",
                "$old_ESTADO_ENVIO"
            ))
        ))
    );
    return pipeline;
}
```

1. Se filtra para detectar operaciones de
   actualización en la colección y para asegurarse de que el campo
   `ESTADO_ENVIO` en el objeto `attributes` ha sido actualizado.
2. Se proyecta solo el campo `ESTADO_ENVIO` del
   objeto `attributes` y se excluye el campo `_id`.
3. Se agrega un campo `old_ESTADO_ENVIO` que
   contiene el valor antiguo del campo `ESTADO_ENVIO`. Si el campo
   `ESTADO_ENVIO` no existía anteriormente, se establece en null.
4. Se filtra para encontrar documentos donde el
   valor actual del campo `ESTADO_ENVIO` es diferente del valor antiguo.

**Otra solución**

Una posible solución es agregar el operador `$set` en el método `Aggregates.project()` en lugar de `Aggregates.match()`. Reemplaza el método `Aggregates.project()` en el pipeline anterior con el siguiente código:

```
Aggregates.project(
    Projections.fields(
        Projections.include("attributes.ESTADO_ENVIO"),
        Projections.excludeId(),
        Projections.computed("old_ESTADO_ENVIO", "$attributes.ESTADO_ENVIO")
    )
)
```

Agregamos el campo `old_ESTADO_ENVIO` al documento proyectado y lo establece con el valor actual del campo `ESTADO_ENVIO` utilizando el operador `$computed`. De esta manera, no necesitas el método `Aggregates.addFields()` para agregar el campo `old_ESTADO_ENVIO`.

Luego, puedes utilizar el operador `$ne` en `Aggregates.match()` para filtrar los documentos donde el valor actual del campo `ESTADO_ENVIO` es diferente del valor antiguo.

Comment: Sigue sin detectar el evento

Comment: he actualizado mi respuesta con otra posible solucion

Comment: nada, sigue sin detectar el evento :(